# Microsoft project Burndown Report dates shifted right by a week

Tags: ms-project, burn-charts

I've created a burndown to show progress over time, but the x-axis dates seem to be shifted to the right by a week:

[image: Burndown, dates shifted]
I can clearly see a flattening out of remaining tasks a week earlier, but I don't understand why that doesn't align with today's date. All tasks have been updated and are current. I've tried editing the timescales but that doesn't help.

Any ideas as to how to fix this, or point me in the right direction if my thinking is wrong?

Comment: What went out a week? What does not align with today's date? What are the relationships between the blue, gray, and orange lines?

Comment: The coloured lines are explained in the key at the top. Blue = baslined remaining tasks, Grey = remaining tasks, Orange = Remaining Actual Tasks. These are standard lines from project's burndown report.
My problem is that the date at which the lines change is a week out.
i.e. today is Thurs 9 Dec 2021
But the date at which the lines change aligns at 29/11/21.

Comment: What's the difference between "remaining tasks" and "remaining actual tasks"?

Comment: They're "standard" graph lines created by ms-project. My interpretation: Remaining tasks includes those that have been either added to or subtracted from the original baseline, and Remaining Actual Tasks are those still to be completed. Since those Remaining Actual Tasks haven't been completed the line remain horizontal until such time as additional tasks are completed over time.